# How to add date and time picker in a JSP page

Tags: html, jsp, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetimepicker

I need to add date and time picker to my JSP page, using the below code, I am able to get the date picker. Could anyone help me out with the date and time picker in JSP.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd%27%3E)
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
 <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Any errors on the web browser console? Its works fine for me. Make sure that your connected to internet :)

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/tengcalendar.shtml. Visit this

Comment: Hi Aravind.. Thanks.. Date picker is fine. I need Timepicker also to be included.